# "And it goes without saying" is referring back or indicating the following sentence?

Tags: reference

> I mean as it flies all the way across the Gulf of Mexico, it uses up almost none of its body fat. But that doesn't mean it doesn't need to eat! So hummingbirds have to rely on plants in their natural habitat. **And it goes without saying**, but... well, the opposite is true as well. Plants depend on hummingbirds too. (A script from TOEFL LISTENING)

Since it is audio, how do I identify whether the bold sentence is referring to what comes before it, "So hummingbirds have to rely on plants in their natural habitat," being pretty self-evident or what comes after, "Plants depend on hummingbirds too"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“It goes without saying” is a fixed phrase that means *the following statement* should be obvious, but I’m going to say it anyway for completeness.